# What configuration determines which Desktop Environment to run?

Tags: kde, xfce, desktop-environment, lightdm, unity

I have a system with multiple Desktop Environments installed (Ubuntu 14.04 with `Unity` and `Xfce`). I would like to configure (with a non-interactive script) a particular DE for a particular user.

How is this controlled? Would it be the same for e.g. `KDE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I'm writing the lightDM configuration when configuring autologin anyway, and that's where I'm specifying the user, so the right thing is to specify the system default at the same time: wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM#Changing_the_Default_Session

However, when this bug is fixed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/1371710
I'll need a better way to set a per-user default since lightdm won't be reconfigured/restarted for each user autologin.

More data: with lightDM, a desktop preference will be looked up in `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/$USER`  (no good docs, but [some tantalizing details here](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2132647.html)), and if not found will be looked up in `$HOME/.dmrc` ([described here](https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/3.14/configuration.html.en#userconfig)). When a user logs in and chooses a DE, both of these locations are populated. So, a script could provision either of these locations (either using the DBus interface or writing to the AccountService file directly) to set a suitable default for the user.

Comment: Although your achieving your desired result, remember that that location is dependant upon using GDM.  The location may be different for KDM and other login managers.

Comment: Unfortunately it's worse than that. .dmrc is indeed specified in the GDM "specification", but AccountsService appears to be narrower than that (Debian/Ubuntu only?) and doesn't appear to be supported by GDM. However for `lightdm` in particular those two locations work. Other Display Managers may indeed use other mechanisms and may not work this way at all. This is a very lightdm-specific solution.

Answer (score -1):

No configuration controls which desktop is Chosen.  If the DE is installed it can be chosen by the user at login using the Session Chooser.  I was going to post screenshots, but they are already [posted here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81161/how-to-remove-session-entries-from-lightdm)

Comment: I don't see how that can be true, because once you choose a configuration, it's the default next time. So that configuration *has* to be stored somewhere. And if a user can choose/set that configuration themselves (via the Session Chooser), surely that same configuration can be created externally, right? I'm guessing it's a file in the user's home directory, or else a gconf setting.

Comment: It depends on what Login Manager you use.  IIRC the login manager reads /etc/X11/sessions/, but that only controls which sessions are on the list, not how the DE is configured.

Comment: eyoung100: I assume you mean Display Manager? Such as lightdm? That's the one I'm particularly interested in.

Comment: In particular, I'm setting up an autologin environment with lightdm, so there is no Session Chooser dialog for the user to utilize.

Comment: Then you're limited to one session I believe.  The user has no say, as Auto-Login is System Wide

Comment: Which brings me to my related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158699/on-a-machine-with-multiple-desktop-environments-set-how-is-the-default-de-confi

Comment: However, I wouldn't be surprised to find that once a user has a default DE set, autologin will use that...

Comment: Don't Double Post.  If you want XFCE in the VM you have to install XFCE in the VM before you provision it, then set it as the default in the VM.  If you install XFCE as the only DE in the VM, then that and a Failsafe are all that's available unless you disable Auto Login

Comment: These are separate questions and I didn't want to risk only one being answered so didn't lump them together. One is about per-user configuration. The other is about default configuration. I referenced the other one to avoid confusion. Yes of course you have to install it first. The (other) question is how to set it as the default once it is installed. Installing it is not sufficient, and I need both DEs installed, unfortunately because I'll be provisioning dynamically for different users, with different choices for DE.

Comment: The only way you can set a per-user desktop is to create `~/.xinitrc` but I believe this is overwritten by the default started by systemd, so it's a moot point, and if the DE isn't installed at the time, running it from the xinitrc will result in an error.

Comment: I can ensure that all necessary DEs are pre-installed. I'll look into .xinitrc thanks.

Comment: See [the ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xinitrc).  Regardless of Distro the file behaves the same.  Consider deleting that other question, and as I said it only works w/ `startx`.

Comment: I figured it out. I'm writing the lightDM configuration when configuring autologin anyway, and that's where I'm specifying the user, so the right thing is to specify the system default at the same time: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM#Changing_the_Default_Session

Comment: Great!! Good Luck

Comment: It's very peculiar that installing xfce4 does not create an entry in /usr/share/xsessions/*.desktop, so that it can be specified as the default. Time to read up on how to cook up such a file.

Comment: Thats because XFCE's Session name is `xfce4-session`

Comment: Yeah my mistake. I forgot I had reverted to a VM snapshot prior to installing Xfce. In fact it does deliver an xfce.desktop file as expected.