# On a machine with multiple Desktop Environments set, how is the default DE configured?

Tags: xfce, desktop-environment, lightdm, unity

I am provisioning systems with multiple Desktop Environments (Ubuntu 14.04, with `Unity` and `Xfce`). I want to change the default DE to Xfce from a non-interactive script (for `autologin` with `lightdm`). How can this be done?

Note this is related to another question I've posted regarding per-user configurations: [What configuration determines which Desktop Environment to run?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158659/what-configuration-determines-which-desktop-environment-to-run)

Answer (score 2):

The answer for setting default configuration is here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM#Changing_the_Default_Session